# Deleted and inserted instead of updated when changing one object's property in Realm

Tags: swift, realm, rx-swift

I'm learning the RxSwift and wanted to use Realm and RxRealm. I've implemented deleting and inserting new items but I've got a problem with updating one value.

Inside database singleton I've got this function:

```
func updateNew(for primaryKey: Int) {
    if let itemToUpdate = realm.object(ofType: Item.self, forPrimaryKey: primaryKey) {
        try! realm.write {
            itemToUpdate.isNew = !itemToUpdate.isNew
        }
    }
}
```

In my view model 'm using RxRealm Observable.changeset and subscribing to results and changes. I can see that if I call this function for primaryKey = 2 then in my `subscribe` I get:

```
deleted: [1]
inserted: [2]

Observable.changeset(from: itemsResult!).subscribe(onNext: { results, changes in
            if let changes = changes {
                print(results)
                print("deleted: \(changes.deleted)")
                print("inserted: \(changes.inserted)")
                print("updated: \(changes.updated)")
                ...
}
```

Why does `changes.updated` is not called?

Comment: I tried it according to your provided code and everything works just fine. `deleted [1]` and `inserted [2]` is printed to console? And `updated: []` is not?

Comment: @kiwisip yes, but why `updated` is empty if I'm changing this value.

Comment: When I tried it, `deleted` and `inserted` was empty and only `updated` contained the updated index (so it worked as it should). I can't tell what your problem might be from what you showed. Try to provide more code (how you create `itemResult`, where do you call `updateNew(for:)` etc..)

Comment: @kiwisip `itemsResult` inside the `init` and it uses `realm.objects(Item.self)` to get `Results<Item>`. `updateNew` is just called when user clicks the cell inside the tableview